# R bindings for SLEPC / PETSC?

Tags: r

Anyone have much luck within bindings for R and SLEPC? Looking for a faster SVD and eigenvalue algorithm in R.

update: I'm generally interested in both scenarios(speed vs scale)

Comment: [Cross posted on R-SIG-HPC](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2012-October/001542.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow:

1. SLEPC is for *scalable* ie very large problems
2. You ask for faster SVDs

If you are after speed, I'd consider

- fast implementations, either something like [RcppEigen](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppEigen) or,
- accelerated BLAS such as OpenBLAS which can be a drop-in for R, if R was built the right way.

But if you are really after large problems, maybe the new [pbd-r.org](http://www.r-pdb.org) project which wraps ScaLAPACK can be of help.

So please let us know if you're after *speed* or *scale*.

Comment: Interested in both scenarios.

Comment: Let me guess: a pony too?  In all seriousness, there are _tradeoffs_ so which do you want first?